# How to fix "error CS1061: 'GoogleMobileAdsSettings' does not contain a definition for 'IsAdMobEnabled'" in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

ever since I am trying to implement adMob mediation I have been running into nightmares in my life. I dont know why I am getting this error of

```
    " error CS1061: 'GoogleMobileAdsSettings' does not contain a definition for 'IsAdMobEnabled' and no accessible extension method 'IsAdMobEnabled' accepting a first argument of type 'GoogleMobileAdsSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

I tried solving this by reimporting all assets and everything but nothing is happening. I again imported a new mediation plugin to see if the files are missing. But nothing seems to work out. I tried to upgrade the unity version as well.[image: Error in Script]

Before this I was getting the utils error,and I dont know what I did it got solved.

Answer (score 1):

The "IsAdMobEnabled" variable is removed from the "GoogleMobileAdsSettings" class in Admob unity plugin 6.0.0 or latest.

//=====Latest Setting

[image]

//=====Older Setting
[image]

See the picture above (lastest setting one), that variable is removed. Means "**Admob Ad Manager**" is removed from the setting "Scriptable object" and "**Google Admob**" mode is totally enabled.

For you, you can consider the "**Google Admob**" as enabled and update your logic according to it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `GoogleMobileAdsSettings.Instance` to `GoogleMobileAdsSettings.LoadInstance()` in every line it will work :)

Comment: Kindly explain the reason this would work.

Comment: The error is because the plugin got updated and the way it handled the instances of itself got changed. I managed to read the code of the updated plugin and compared it with the old one to find a fix for this issue. So for others who are having this issue can follow my simple procedures to fix this issue without going through that code and debugging for a while. I hope this will help someone saving few hours! :)